# How to save and load textBox Font in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, file

I want save textBox Font in  txt File

This is my code

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path", txtNotepad.Font.ToString());
```

Then I Want to Read The Font From TXT File By The Following Code

```
String fontName = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path");
```

How to Change The TextBox Font by FontName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with the [Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class, consider using the provided [FontConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontconverter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead of trying to parse the results of `System.Drawing.Font.ToString()` yourself.

Here's an example:

```
// Use the provided converter to get and store a culture-invariant string.
var converter = new FontConverter();
string fontInfo = converter.ConvertToInvariantString(txtNotepad.Font);
File.WriteAllText("path", fontInfo);

// Retrieve the string and set the Font property on your TextBox.
fontInfo = File.ReadAllText("path");
txtNotepad.Font = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(fontInfo) as Font;
```

This approach prevents you from reinventing the wheel and provides handling for other culture formats.